# c++ define directive fails and code looks OK

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am trying to build the mongo-cxx-driver library

```
mmuratet@fisher:~/mongo-cxx-driver/build$ cmake --prefix=/usr/local ..
-- No build type selected, default is Release
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mmuratet/mongo-cxx-driver/build

mmuratet@fisher:~/mongo-cxx-driver/build$ make
[  3%] Built target EP_mnmlstc_core
[ 10%] Built target bsoncxx
[ 16%] Built target bsoncxx_static
[ 21%] Built target test_bson
[ 22%] Building CXX object src/mongocxx/CMakeFiles/mongocxx.dir/bulk_write.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/libbson-1.0/bson-compat.h:38:0,
             from /usr/local/include/libbson-1.0/bson.h:23,
             from /home/mmuratet/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/private/libbson.hpp:17,
             from /home/mmuratet/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/bulk_write.cpp:18:
/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0/bson-macros.h:48:28: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 #  define BSON_END_DECLS   }
                        ^
/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0/mongoc-stream-tls-private.h:61:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘BSON_END_DECLS’
 BSON_END_DECLS
```

^
        make[2]: *** [src/mongocxx/CMakeFiles/mongocxx.dir/bulk_write.cpp.o] Error 1
        make[1]: *** [src/mongocxx/CMakeFiles/mongocxx.dir/all] Error 2
        make: *** [all] Error 2

and get the error above.

Here is the offending code (line #s added by less):

```
 46 #ifdef __cplusplus
 47 #  define BSON_BEGIN_DECLS extern "C" {
 48 #  define BSON_END_DECLS   }
 49 #else
 50 #  define BSON_BEGIN_DECLS
 51 #  define BSON_END_DECLS
 52 #endif
```

This code looks OK to me. Can someone point out what I have missed? Could there be a problem upstream in the includes? How would one go about finding it?

Cheers

Comment: I think you can only define constants or function macros, but not a part of a block.

Comment: Can you show the code where it complains about the macro expansion?

Comment: What version of the c++11 driver? What version of the C driver? What compiler? What platform?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're using libmongoc from the master branch, which appears to have a bug where that BSON_END_DECLS isn't paired with a BEGIN_DECLS above (it was dropped out by accident in a previous commit)

I've filed a bug at: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-1162

The 1.3.4 tag is an actual stable release and doesn't appear to have the same problem.